# Add column with custom value to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm attempting to add a new column to an existing R `dataframe` that will add a new column depending on value within corresponding row value. If value is `1` new column value should contain `one` , if value is `2` new column value should contain `two` , otherwise `three or more`

This code :

```
mydf <- data.frame(a = 1:6, 
                   b = rep("reproducible", 6),
                   c = rep("example", 6), 
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
mydf
```

renders :

[image]

Using code :

```
    mydf["encoded"] <- { if (mydf['a'] == 1) 'one' else if (mydf['a'] == 2) 'two' else 'three or more' }
mydf
```

renders :

[image]

A warning is also generated :

```
Warning message in if (mydf["a"] == 1) "one" else if (mydf["a"] == 2) "two" else "three or more":
“the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”
```

A new column is added to `dataframe` but all values are same : `one`

I've not implemented the logic to add the new column values correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution using [`dplyr::case_when`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/case_when):**

Syntax and logic is self-explanatory: when `a` is equal to `1` - `encoded` is equal to "one"; when `a` is equal to `2` - `encoded` is equal to "two"; all other cases - encoded is equal to "three or more".
And `mutate` just creates a new column.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(mydf, encoded = case_when(a == 1 ~ "one",
                                 a == 2 ~ "two",
                                 TRUE ~ "three or more"))

  a            b       c       encoded
1 1 reproducible example           one
2 2 reproducible example           two
3 3 reproducible example three or more
4 4 reproducible example three or more
5 5 reproducible example three or more
6 6 reproducible example three or more
```

---

**Solution using [`base::ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/ifelse):**

```
mydf$encoded <- ifelse(mydf$a == 1, 
                       "one", 
                       ifelse(mydf$a == 2, 
                              "two",
                              "three or more"))
```

If you don't like writing `mydf$a` multiple times you can use `with`:

```
mydf$encoded <- with(mydf, ifelse(a == 1, 
                                  "one", 
                                  ifelse(a == 2, 
                                         "two",
                                         "three or more")))
```

Answer (score 3):

A much overlooked function to do this is the `cut` function:

```
mydf$encoded <- cut(mydf$a, c(0:2,Inf), c('one','two','three or more'))
```

The result:

```
> mydf
  a            b       c       encoded
1 1 reproducible example           one
2 2 reproducible example           two
3 3 reproducible example three or more
4 4 reproducible example three or more
5 5 reproducible example three or more
6 6 reproducible example three or more
```

Comment: This is better than hand writing the conditions :) like you answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

`sapply` can also do the job:

```
mydf$encoded <- sapply(
    mydf$a, function(a) 
        if (a == 1) 'one' else if (a == 2) 'two' else 'three or more')
mydf
#   a            b       c       encoded
# 1 1 reproducible example           one
# 2 2 reproducible example           two
# 3 3 reproducible example three or more
# 4 4 reproducible example three or more
# 5 5 reproducible example three or more
# 6 6 reproducible example three or more
```